# Set default initial time in UIDatePicker ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

In my UIDatePicker need to display today as a default date but specific time as a default time. Bydefault it gets current time. How to set it manually?

```
_datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[_datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
_datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
```

Comment: `[_datePicker setDate:theDateOfTodayWithTheDefaultTimeYourWant]`?

Comment: @Larme [NSDate date] gives current time as well. So how to give date and time separately.

Comment: Then your question is about: How do I create a date at specific hour and minutes? Then it's there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288671/how-to-set-time-on-nsdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a today date without time and then set the time manually on it to get a date you need. Date components are perfect for that:

```
func getTodayDate(at: (hour: Int, minute: Int)) -> Date {
    let dateComponents = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
    dateComponents.hour = at.hour
    dateComponents.minute = at.minute
    return Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(from: dateComponents)
}
```

Objective-C

```
- (NSDate *)getTodayDateAt:(NSInteger)hour minute:(NSInteger)minute {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    components.hour = hour;
    components.minute = minute;
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Now just set it to your date picker:

```
_datePicker.date = ...
```

Make sure your date picker uses the same calendar though.

Comment: Actually this is what I need.